# Strapi Nextjs, build a nav with one nested category

Tags: api, next.js, navbar, nested-lists, strapi

I'm building a nav on nextjs, with headless API on strapi.
I have 6 menu items, but one of them must have 2 submenus.

What is the best way to proceed? How to create nested catergories on strapi?

On my frontend, I use .map to render the list of catagories. Should I separate the one with the submenus from the rest of the menu?

nav.js

```
<Navbar>
        <Row>
          <Navbar.Brand>
          <Link href="/actualites">
            <a className="logo"> FACT</a>
          </Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Row>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <ul className="menu">
            {categories.sort(function(a,b) {
            return  a.nb - b.nb;
            }).map((category) => {
              return (
                <li key={category.id}>
                  <Link as={`/category/${category.slug}`} href="/category/[id]">
                    <a>{category.name}</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
```